# Can somebody explain in simple terms why Django throws a "NoReverseMatch at /" error

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

The errors are mainly categorized as
1) "NoReverseMatch at /"
2) "Error during template rendering"

Comment: Sorry my crystal ball is out for repair. But perhaps we could help more if you posted the relevant code and the full traceback...

Comment: sorry about that! the traceback is http://dpaste.com/1520989/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you have this in your template:

```
{% url "bmark_bookmark_user" bookmark.owner.username %}
```

and this in your traceback:

```
Reverse for 'bmark_bookmark_user' with arguments '(u'mario',)' and
keyword arguments '{}' not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/(?P<username>[-\\w+])/$']
```

Your regexp uses a named group `(?P<username>[-\\w+])`, which tells Django you want to use a keyword argument for you view. It also means you have to use keyword arguments to try to reverse the url, IOW:

```
{% url "bmark_bookmark_user" username=bookmark.owner.username %}
```

in templates and

```
reverse("bmark_bookmark_user", kwargs=dict(username=bookmark.owner.username))
```

in Python code.

Also your pattern won't work as you expect:

```
>>> re.match("(?P<username>[-\\w+])", "mario").groups()
('m',)
```

You very probably want `"^/user/(?P<username>[-\\w]+)/$"` instead:

```
>>> re.match("(?P<username>[-\\w]+)", "mario").groups()
('mario',)
```

Comment: Hi Bruno! I'm still getting the same error, my views.py looks like this http://dpaste.com/1521017/

Comment: If that's another error then update your question with the correction AND the full traceback. If it's the same error, post your urls.py file.

Comment: Yeah I getting the same error. my urls.py is this http://dpaste.com/1521026/

Comment: See my edited answer about your regexp.

Comment: Bruno, I've basically tried out this http://django-marcador.readthedocs.org/en/latest/urls_views.html with some modifications; please see if there is any bug in the documentation

Answer (score -1):

The important error message is

```
Exception Value: Reverse for 'bmark_bookmark_user' with arguments '(u'mario',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/(?P<username>[-\\w+])/$']
```

You try to render url by `{% url bmark_bookmark_user 'mario' %}` that `bmark_bookmark_user` with username `mario` does not match the pattern.

How about

`^user/(?P<username>[0-9A-Za-z-_.]+)/$'`

and give quotes,

`{% url 'bmark_bookmark_user' 'mario' %}`

If you're sure your url is valid but still found error, try to put `load url from future` at first line of your template (just to make sure that url is imported).

Comment: None of your "explanations" match the error message, and `urlresolver.reverse` just doesn't know zilch about your model- it just try to reverse build an url based on the pattern and argument.